# Move Text Up Over Image On Hover

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to emulate what [The Dissolve](http://thedissolve.com/) does on their page (at the bottom), making the title of the article move up over the image and reveal an excerpt, using only CSS. I've set up a JS Fiddle in which I'm close, but not quite there. It's easy to get caught in limbo if your mouse is near the bottom of the image while the excerpt is trying to close. Any thoughts on how to improve my code without using javascript?

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/27sdzs28/5/)

- Updated my JS Fiddle example with the 
  `clear:both` suggestion from Celmar which fixed that issue.

Comment: i think you want to make it something like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/27sdzs28/2/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes - No, that's not quite right. In your example, the title isn't showing by default, plus it takes over the whole image when hovering, unlike what I'm attempting to emulate above.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/27sdzs28/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any thoughts on how to improve my code without using javascript?

1. Do not changes on position property in trigger selector (.sub-story:hover .sub-text in this case) don't work as naturally expected.
2. Put the transitions on base selector (.sub-story .sub-text) not in trigger selector. Unless you want the animation suddenly reversed when removing the trigger condition. (mouse leave)

Example that mimic The Dissolve (from the strach)

*Changed .sub-story for .figure and .sub-text for .title*

Note: Remove the text formats to highlight the properties of the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/6h74q0tq/2/

```css
/** Base Selectors */

.figure {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     width: 376px;
     height: 300px;
}

.figure .title {
     /* Put transitions here */
     -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     
     /* Put potitioning here */
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: 1;  
     
     background: #fff;
}

.figure .title .date {
     -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     transition: all 500ms ease-in;
  
     opacity: 0;  
}

.figure .details {
     -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     transition: all 500ms ease-in;
     -webkit-transition-delay: 500ms; 
     -mox-transition-delay: 500ms;
     transition-delay: 500ms;
  
     position: absolute;
     width: 376px;     
     height: 90px;
     bottom: 0;
     z-index: 0;
     opacity: 0;
}

/** Trigger Selectors */

.figure:hover .title {    
   /** Just change the animated properties */
   bottom: 90px;
}

.figure:hover .title .date {
   opacity: 1;
}

.figure:hover .details {    
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/376/202" alt="cat1" />
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Cat of the week <span class="date">OCTOBER 5</span></h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <div class="author">RnrNeverDies :P</div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
<div class="figure">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/376/202" alt="cat1" />
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Cat of the week <span class="date">OCTOBER 5</span></h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <div class="author">RnrNeverDies :P</div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
<div class="figure">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/376/202" alt="cat1" />
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Cat of the week <span class="date">OCTOBER 5</span></h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <div class="author">RnrNeverDies :P</div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
<div class="figure">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/376/202" alt="cat1" />
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Cat of the week <span class="date">OCTOBER 5</span></h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <div class="author">RnrNeverDies :P</div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

[Source](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index3.html)

Comment: This helps a lot! One thing I noticed though is when the title length varies (which it will), the pictures don't line up anymore. Take a look at my updated JS Fiddle example based on your code. http://jsfiddle.net/27sdzs28/7/ Any ideas?

Comment: checkout http://jsfiddle.net/27sdzs28/8/, it's just a patch, I think you can not fix this with pure css, but you can use js to change the font size if the box expands. maybe use lettering.js

Comment: Yeah, definitely a patch. I guess I'm not opposed to javascript if it's needed to accomplish this. Though how much javascript would be required?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the 'shifting' of the entire page, add this between the second and third sub-story element (Basically, where a new row starts). That issue is caused by float positioning of elements of different heights.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: That did fix the page shifting up issue. Any ideas on how to fix the "limbo" glitch when hovering over the title at the bottom?